# Progress is not increasing in progress dialog Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, progressdialog

I am using the following code in Android Studio:

```
    final ProgressDialog pr1 = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pr1.setMessage("Loading... ");
    pr1.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    pr1.setIndeterminate(true);
    pr1.setProgress(0);
    pr1.setMax(99);
    pr1.show();
    final Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int i;
            for(i=0;i<=99;i++) {
                //some code here
                pr1.incrementProgressBy(1);
            }
            pr1.dismiss();
        }
    });
    t1.start();
```

now whenever i run this, progress dialog shows and run but the progress bar can not increment its just showing off.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]. We should be able to compile the coffee you provide without any extra compiler errors.

Comment: sorry i don't understands you what you are asking for?

Comment: Please read the link I gave. Specifically, your code shown here does not have a class or a method.

Comment: see 'onebuttondev' gave the correct answer/solution to my problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot show increment in an indeterminate progressbar.

As per the Android docs: "In indeterminate mode, the progress bar shows a cyclic animation without an indication of progress."

If you want to show progess you have to change your line setIndeterminate(true) and make it false.

Comment: thank you very much.. it works now.. i just made setIndeterminate to false.

Comment: Glad I could help!